# seam-gen gives names like clientClientId and facilityFacilityId is there a reason for this madness?

Tags: seam, seam-gen

I get a lot of redundant variable names from seamGen  (clientClientId and facilityFacilityId)
and I often change them manually to eliminate confusion.  Is Seam doing something special (AOP related magic) with these names?  Is there a way to prevent seam-gen from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your DB has composite primary keys, maybe?

Comment: No, definitely not. All are of the form client_id, facility_id, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the case for all entities generated?  Are your table names in the form of n_SOME_TABLE_NAME?  I read somewhere that seam-gen doesn't always play well with that format.